# Inherit/Extend Django Module or cram into same Module?

Tags: python, django, module

For an upcoming project, I will have a Site that basically defines the user workflow as 3 steps. Task, check, publish. The task is something a regular user does. Check is some kind of QA by admins and publish is a post processing step.

In the beginning there will only be a single task, however, in the future we want to have more types of tasks, of different nature.

### Example

The task could be to solve a list of mathematical problems and submit the solutions. Another task could be, showing three pictures and the user has to tell which pictures contain the same object. The tasks are different, but will boil down to being a task, that will need checking.

In checking: there are supposed to be several types of checking. For the math for example, we could have an auto checking comparing previously set solutions, whereas the picture task will need human support, to see if the user did the task properly. 
You can see, that certain tasks come with certain checks. However, for the picture task we could have different kind of checks again.

We could do a full check, a spot check, or take a majority vote of several users performing the same task, or something completely different.

Publishing will publish a checked task in several ways: report, blogpost, write to database, generate a list of problematic tasks.

### Modules

Tasks are different but they are tasks. Hence, I consider having a module for every task, however, they are all tasks. Hence there are 2 things I want to accomplish:

- have a base definition of a task
- have tasks under same task namespace

The same holds for checking and publishing

### How to achieve this / Questions

Does it make sense to have so many Modules? To me it does. I am likely to reuse a certain task for another project!

Have a single module hold all kinds of tasks is a bad idea. Therefore, extend a base module! Is it possible? (i am positive it is, bc python and django are awesome, but a few pointers would be good)

I would love to have all task modules in the same folder/namespace. I know it might be bad for reusability (picking single task) however, for other developers it will be easier to see where their new task goes. Is it possible to have submisules, or group modules of the same type in the same folder and route /task to that folder?

Have checking modules outside of the task. Checking might be reused, for tasks of a similar structure. Therefore different tasks can have the same checking modules applied. Checking is different from task, so i want it to be a module and then later assign a specific checking module to a certain task.

### Discuss

This was my story :) i hope my ideas make sense and that a django veteran can tell my if i make sense or not and whether ir not it is possible at all!

#### apology

Im typing this with my phone because Im running out of time and have no one to discuss this with. Please bear with the format of my post, until i can get to my computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a folder structure like this:

```
myproject
-> task
----> models
--------> __init__.py
--------> base.py
--------> math.py
--------> etc.
----> views
--------> __init__.py
--------> math.py
--------> etc.
----> urls
--------> __init__.py
--------> etc.
-> check
----> models
--------> __init__.py
--------> base.py
--------> etc.

-etc.- (you get the idea)
```

This way, you'll divide your Django project in three separate apps, and you'll divide each apps' models, views, forms, etc. into separate files.

To import a specific model, view, form etc. you'll just do:

```
from task.models.math import MathTask
from task.views.image import ImageView
etc.
```

This is how you'll make the abstract base models:

```
class BaseTask(models.Model):
    # your fields goes here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: PS: I'm no *Django veteran* by any means, I've just started using Django.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. At first glance this looks promising! Being python modules, i can create subfolders in the tasks if necessary. Then i will add one mire module to actually display the page skeleton and access the corresponding modules right?

Comment: Yes, if you need a *home* app with links to the different views, you should probably create that as well.

Comment: I went for a slightly different structure based on yours and everything works like a charm! thanks! Gotta love Django :3 Fell in love with it all over again!